# Communication between two microcontrollers with different operating voltages (5 V and 3.3 V)

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, level-shifting, level-translation

I want to communicate between two microcontrollers - one is PIC18F2550 and the other is STM32F103VET. They operate at different voltages: 5 V (PIC) and 3.3 V (STM32). I would prefer to use SPI communication.

The problem is, I couldn't connect two microcontrollers operating at different voltages directly. There might be some trick I need. Is there anyone else who could help me out?

Comment: Here are some relevant search terms which you can research (I added tags to help future readers): level translation, level shifting, five-volt tolerant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Andy's answer, in case your available MCU pins are not capable of receiving different voltage, you can either build a level translation circuit (as described here [1.8V UART with 3.3V UART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333229/1-8v-uart-with-3-3v-uart)), or use a ready-made level translation development board (for example https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009 ), or finally use a specific IC for thah job ( for example https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1622023837184&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fgr.mouser.com%252F ) . The choice is yours, according to your needs (UART, I2C, SPI etc ) and the parts available.

Answer (score 2):

For the receiving on the 5 volt side you can pick a buffer that runs from a 5 volt rail and is capable of recognizing a 3.3 volt signal as a logical 1. Virtually any buffer with a TTL compatible input will do this.

For the receiving on the 3.3 volt side, you can find buffers that are capable of dealing with a 5 volt input even though they operate on a 3.3 volt rail. Alternatively, use a potential divider to reduce 5 volt compatible levels to 3.3 volt compatible rails.